# Build standalone .exe from electron app using electron-builder

Tags: windows, macos, electron, installation, electron-builder

I'm using electron v6.0.9 with electron-builder v21.2.0. Here is the packaging configuration from my `package.json` for a production build.

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.app.prototype",
    "productName": "Pluto",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Simon Inc.",
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        "zip"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "publisherName": "Simon Inc.",
      "target": [
        "nsis",
        "zip"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "tar.gz"
      ]
    },
    "dmg": {
      "icon": "build/icon.icns"
    },
    "publish": {
      "provider": "generic",
      "url": "THE_RELEASE_URL_HERE",
      "channel": "latest",
      "publishAutoUpdate": true
    }
  },
```

I configured the build script as `"pack": "electron-builder --dir -mwl",` in `script`. The issue is, when i run the command `npm run pack`, it packages the application for all the platform, but for windows there is no single installer file either `.exe` or '.msi'. `electron-builder` builds bunch of files for windows.

I'm running on macOS High Sierra v10.13.6 (17G8030). I also tried building on windows 10 system but outcome is the same. is anything misconfigured here or there some more steps required to generate single installer file for windows?

Comment: Where you have define that with method you are using for window ? means its `nsis`,`appX` or `squirrel.windows`

Comment: look at my `package.json` above. I'm targetting nsis and zip

Comment: you figure this out? i tried using `electron-packager`, and it simply creates a folder with a bunch of files including the `exe`. is there any way to package the electron application like a normal program, whereby you run the `exe` to install the application in the system etc?

Comment: @BugWhisperer Yes, using `electron-builder` and target for `nsis`. Run `electron-builder -p never --win` to build the installer. check the answer for details

Comment: sweet thanks BUT you forgot to link to the answer??

Comment: also, is it possible to create desktop shortcuts etc?

Comment: @BugWhisperer After install the .exe generated, it will create a desktop shortcut also.

Comment: i could only get `electron-packager` working. i had troubles trying to use `electron-builder`, so i have one last question: when using `electron-builder` to create the `.exe` executable, if the user clicks the `.exe`, does it prompt the user to choose which folder to install it to?

Comment: Yes, You can configure the electron-builder to do so.

Comment: How do you set it up so that **the user can choose which folder** to unpack the `exe` upon installation?

Comment: can you provide me with a link to some info regarding that?

Comment: @BugWhisperer everything is here https://www.electron.build/ if you still can't find anything. comment here i'll try to post minimal example here

Comment: i found it `"nsis": { "oneClick": false }`, but, although this creates the install popup window, it doesnt let the user choose which window? -- NEVERMIND, its right underneath :D sorry for spam of msgs

Comment: nevermind my friend, it was right underneath. (sorry for spam of msgs)

Comment: If it doesn't late the user select the install location, it's definitely installed it on app data. I checked in electron-based app (VSCode), It also gets installed in AppData

Comment: try adding `"allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true` in `nsis` build config

Comment: its because `"allowToChangeInstallationDirectory"` defaults to `false`. i have to make that true i think

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out about how to build a standalone installer from electron source rather than having a bunch of files. Actually we have to use `electron-builder` with `-p`. 
Here is the build configuration in my **package.json** file.

```js
"build": {
    "appId": "com.trinityinfosystem.accurate",
    "productName": "Accurate",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Trinity InfoSystem",
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        "zip"
      ],
      "publish": [
        "github"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "publisherName": "Trinity InfoSystem",
      "publish": [
        "github"
      ],
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "tar.gz"
      ]
    },
    "dmg": {
      "icon": "build/icon.icns"
    },
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "github",
        "owner": "vkiranmaniya",
        "repo": "accurate",
        "vPrefixedTagName": true,
        "private": true,
        "releaseType": "draft"
      }
    ]
  }
```

then i just used `electron-builder -p never --win` and it packed up the **.exe** file in *project_root/dist* directory. You can use `-p always` if you are using `auto-updator` from `electron-builder` and want to publish a release draft in github repository.

If you want to override default install location and let the user choose it, make sure you have configured the `nsis` build as follow,

```js
"nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
},
```